# Can't find data file using bool FileExists IsolatedStorageFile

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7

I have a project, I add a data file named "Test" into the project and use:

```
IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

if (!isf.FileExists("Test"))
    return;

imgStream = isf.OpenFile("Test", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(imgStream);
int count = r.ReadInt32();
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    ..........................
}
```

While debugging, the app cannot find the data file in the project, `!isf.FileExists("Test")` returns true. Why?

Answer (score 2):

FileExists determines whether the specified path refers to an existing file in the isolated store.

If you didn't create the file in the IsolatedStorage before, it will tell you that the file doesn't exist.

Files added to a project in Visual Studio are not placed in IsolatedStorage.